# Tooltip container is showing underground item

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have a HTML form with some questions and a select tag for the answers.
I'd like to explain those answers with a tooltip.

HTML

```
<div id="domanda">
<div class="help-tip">
<p> some text</p></div>
This is the question:
</div><div id="scelte">
<select name="finalita">
<option value="1">Answer 1</option> 
<option value="2">Answer 2</option>
</select></div>
```

CSS

```
#domanda{
font-size: 18px;
}
#scelte{
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.help-tip{
display: inline-block;
top: 18px;
right: 18px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #BCDBEA;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 26px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.help-tip:before{
content:'?';
font-weight: bold;
color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
display: block;
transform-origin: 100% 0%;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.help-tip p{    /* The tooltip */
display: none;
text-align: left;
background-color: #1E2021;
padding: 20px;
width: 800px;
position: right;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
right: -4px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 1.4;
}

.help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
display: none;
}    

.help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
width:100%;
height:40px;
content:'';
position: absolute;
top:-40px;
left:0;
}

/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
0% { 
    opacity:0; 
    transform: scale(0.6);
}

100% {
    opacity:100%;
    transform: scale(1);
}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:100%; }
}
```

The issue is that is showing also what's under the tooltip paragraph as you can see here
[image]

This is the picture when the mouse is not hovering
[image]

I spent a while tryin to fix it but without success. What's wrong with my css?

Comment: to your tooltip class ".help-tip" class add position relative and z-index:10; 10 :z-index value is as an example only.

Comment: I suppose you can make Business transparent on hover. Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: Adding position: relative; on the .help-tip:hover p fixed it. Thanks a lot @vssadineni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `position: relative;` to the **.help-tip:hover p** fixed it.
Thanks to vssadineni